# How can I recover information or fix the c # error cs0246?

Tags: c#, cs0246

I am getting this error in My project:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'fooroshEntities' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   foorosh D:\system\foorosh\foorosh\window\Win_AddNewprice.xaml.cs    31  Active
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: This very common error is self-explanatory in most cases. See marked duplicates for some examples of the sadly all-too-common questions posted here in spite of that. If after actually doing some research on your own, exploring the usual reasons for getting the error, and ruling out the usual fixes, you still have trouble, post a new question, but this time make sure you put some time and care into it, making sure you include a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, as well as explaining what you've done so far to try to fix it, and what _specifically_ you can't figure out.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add a reference to DLL or project that is defining fooroshEntities

Comment: there is in My reference but I can't use it

Comment: why? what happens if you try to add that reference?

Comment: Update your question about why you are not able to add a reference to assembly. Otherwise people will mark your question as duplicate